# Selecting nulls by grouped rows SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, having-clause

I have a table that looks like this

```
UniqueID  BeginDate EndDate
045318    12-1-2019 NULL
034557    12-4-2018 NULL
034557    12-4-2019 NULL
054678    12-4-2019 12-05-2019
054678    12-4-2019 NULL
```

I am trying to write a query that selects the uniqueID when there are two or more rows with the same uniqueID and both have null values in the end date column. Based on the table above, I want my output to look like this:

```
UniqueID     EndDate
034557        NULL
```

So far my query would include unique ID `045318` from the example above. Here is what I have so far..

```
SELECT UniqueID, MAX(EndDate) FROM TABLE GROUP BY UniqueID HAVING MAX(EndDate) IS NULL;
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need one additional condition in the `HAVING` cause that filters on `UniqueID`s that have at least 2 records:

```
SELECT UniqueID, MAX(EndDate) 
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY UniqueID 
HAVING MAX(EndDate) IS NULL AND COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks so much!